# Visual Studio opens blank webpage on first (sometimes second) build

Tags: visual-studio

Occasionally, when I run a build using Ctrl+F5 or just F5, Visual Studio completes the build and opens the browser but fails to actually show the site.  Usually this happens the first time I'm building after opening VS, and disappears later.  Anybody have any ideas why this is happening?

**EDIT:** Response to comments:  This is Windows XP with Visual Studio Professional 2008.  When I use View Source it only displays the open and close HTML tags.

Comment: Windows XP, VS Professional 2008.

Comment: Can you see anything in View Source in your browser when you get that blank page?

Comment: Just the open and close HTML tags.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, and I had thoughtlessly used the Application_Error to elegantly handle a HttpRequestValidationException ("dirty" text input on a form) and had inadvertantly muted every other type of exception.

Whenever there was some small syntactical error or error in code, the page would come back blank, making debugging extremely tough.

The symptom was a perfectly formed blank html page.
Hope that helps someone - I realise this is three years old!